# StdIn pipe does not flush when input data is not bug enough?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm working on the program that starts a process, then writes to the stdIn of the process and reads from stdOut of the same process.

My problem is that if I have not big set of data to write to stdIn, for example 1 byte, I can not get the data from stdOut, because `ReadAsync` function of the stdOut never returns.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Framework: dotnet core 2.2
Language: C#

Here is code that I use to write to stdIn:

```
    public static async Task WriteToStdInAsync(
        Stream input,
        Stream stdIn
        )
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
        int read;
        while ((read = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await stdIn.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        await stdIn.FlushAsync();
    }
```

I read from "input" stream whose size is 1 byte and then pass the data to stdIn stream.

Then I'm trying to get that byte back this way:

```
    public static async Task ReadFromStdOutAsync(
        Stream output,
        Stream stdOut
        )
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
        int read;
        while ((read = await stdOut.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

`await stdOut.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` - never returns in this case.

If I increase the size of input stream to 100KB(less values does not work) it works fine. Also it works for small size if I close the stdIn stream after sending all data to stdIn. As you can see I tried to flush stdIn to force data transmission, but it does not work. I assume there is additional level of bufferization in OS that does not allow stdOut to see the data.

Here is how I create the process:

```
        return new Process() {
            EnableRaisingEvents = false,                    
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = "python3",
                Arguments = $"{Settings.PipesEchoServer}",                    
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            },
        };
```

I tried to check the source code of FileStream, Stream, Process, but could not find the answer.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Stream.cs
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/FileStream.cs
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Unix.cs

Will appreciate for any help.

Edited:

I get streams this way:

```
        p.StandardInput.BaseStream,
        p.StandardOutput.BaseStream,
```

where `p` is an instance of `Process` class

Edited2: 
I think I found the problem. I use the python script:

```py
import sys

read = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1024)
while len(read) != 0:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(read)
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
    read = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1024 * 100)
```

but looks like `sys.stdin.buffer.read` does not return results until all 1024 bytes are red from stdIn. I changed it to `sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)` and now it works.

Not sure btw that it's the best way to work with pipes in python, but this is the easiest way that I found how to transfer binary data.

Thanks GottZ for idea to read about `setvbuf`

Comment: there is a function for setting the type of io buffering in c `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` you might want to check out if you can make use of that in c#. the line sets stdout to line buffering. maybe look closer into the options you have with `setvbuf`

Comment: I call a python script that uses `sys.stdout.buffer` to redirect data to stdout. I use it, because I have not found better way how to transfer binary data from stdin to stdout. I changed the way how I read from buffer from `sys.stdin.buffer.read(1024* 100)` to `sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)` and it helped. Looks like `sys.stdin.buffer.read` does not return a value until all number of bytes are got

Comment: ye. it's a buffered pipe. always. nice to see you found a solution. if you want to have a custom protocol you could for example add a small header that would signal how much data will come with the next read

Comment: having header is a good idea, I will keep it in mind when I move further from this POC to the real program. thanks a lot :)